# Unexpected JSON token at start of NPM catalog data - NodeJs in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: node.js, gulp, visual-studio-2017

I am new to NodeJs and trying to Build a application with visual studio 2017 using "Blank NodeJs Web Application"

and Now I need to add the gulp using VS but It gives me an error mentioned as bellow,
[image]

and in the output console, following error occurs

```
       Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException: Unexpected JSON token at start of NPM catalog data
   at Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NpmGetCatalogCommand.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<ParseResultsAndAddToDatabase>b__0()
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.RunInTransaction(Action action)
   at Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NpmGetCatalogCommand.ParseResultsAndAddToDatabase(TextReader reader, String dbFilename, String registryUrl)
   at Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NpmGetCatalogCommand.<>c__DisplayClass23_2.<ExecuteAsync>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: Is this any help? https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/1317

Comment: @Lissy Thanks but it is not working :-(

Comment: Hmm ok, what have you tried so far? (add it to your question, it'll help people answer)#

Comment: I tried following things
* by deleting Node Cache folder
* recreating project
* cleaning temp files,

Answer (score 0):

I tried re-installing VS and other required tools and It worked